# Offline Contribution receipts does not contain custom fields information

Tags: civicontribute, custom-fields

Currently using CiviCRM 5.9.1 and drupal 7.63

Contribution receipts works as expected if the checkbox to send receipt is checked while creating offline contribution. Receipts for offline contributions sent from `Print Contribution Receipts` task does not contain custom fields added for contribution.

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

1. Add custom fields of your choice for Contributions.
2. Create an offline contribution.
3. Go to `Find contribution` and select the contribution and select the option of `Receipts Print or Email` this will send email for the selected contributions.
4. Check the receipt received and see if you get Contribution related
   custom fields in the email.

Anyone is facing this issue?

Comment: Can you please try your use case on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ ?

Comment: Tried same steps on demo site and able to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the receipt template for off-line contributions includes the tokens/code to pull in the custom fields. You might want to compare your templates for each - https://www.domain.com/civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1 and select System Workflow Messages - and compare the two. Then you can attempt copying/pasting in code from the online template and test the email that goes out.

Comment: Thanks! Receipt template for off-line contribution includes code to pull custom fields. And if I sent the email while creating off-line contribution (With the checkbox to send receipts be checked) its working as expected. This issue occurs only when I need to resent the receipt or download PDF of receipts (Using find contributions) then the email or PDF does not contain custom fields.